# WordPress Permalink feature alternative

Tags: permalinks, filters

I'm trying to prefix my permalinks for some backend logic to emulate posts on Multisite.

I have used the [`post_link` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_link) but unfortunately it didn't meet my needs as it doesn't prefix the permalink for custom post types (annoyingly!)

Does anyone know of a method that I can prefix custom post type permalinks with?

For example `www.domain.com/PREFIX/post-slug-here/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For custom post types, use the [`post_type_link` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_type_link) just a you would use the `post_link` filter for `post` post type posts

Comment: How did I miss that! Spent hours banging my head against the wall with this one! Thanks so much!!

Comment: My pleasure. We all go through that type of day. Know I still do have them. Enjoy :-)